# chartboost integration errors on xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, chartboost

I tried integrating chartboost into my app in xcode, using this code:

```
Chartboost *cb = [Chartboost sharedChartboost];

cb.appId = @"Y51071e9d17ba47414f000000";
cb.appSignature = @"51071e9d17ba47414f000000";

// Begin a user session
[cb startSession];

// Show an interstitial
[cb showInterstitial];
```

in `applicationDidBecomeActive`.

But I get this error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Chartboost",
>   referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
>   (use -v to see invocation)

What am I doing wrong, and what should I do?

Comment: Does the library supported to build in iOS Simulator? What if you compile & run in real device?

Comment: I still get those errors when archiving

Comment: It should not be the same error, as real device is NOT architecture i386; it should be ARMv6 or ARMv7.

Comment: It's the same error, but with armv7

Comment: Fixed it, I had to add chartboost.a to the libraries :)

Comment: it is suggested you can answer your question below.

Answer (score 1):

Yep you got it, make sure the chartboost library is added to your project and all frameworks are linked.

If you run into any more issues, take a look at the example project here: https://github.com/ChartBoost/client-examples